# Minimally-permissive outbound security rule for Ubuntu EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

Clients are asking aggressive questions about Data Loss Prevention.

One obvious way to limit the effects of a system being compromised is to do something a bit more restrictive than 0.0.0.0/0 for the outbound security rule.  Numerous security guides also recommend limiting these rules, but I don't see any examples about what actually needs to be allowed.

Many instances only need to access package repos, but in experimentation, allowing access to the `us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com` IP addresses on 80 is NOT enough. (For my us-west-2 instance.)  What else is required?  The apt logs aren't being very helpful.

Comment: It would help if you clarify the question better.  Are you asking about overall best practices on how to lock down outbound Internet access from an EC2 instance (using less permissive outbound security group rules)?  Or are you specifically asking about how to lock down outbound access to package repositories?  If the latter, you may want to offer additional details on the version of Ubuntu that you're using.

Comment: The general rule is easy: "Don't permit access to anything you don't need".  But that's worthless for this specific case.  As for the version of Ubuntu, I don't see how that is at issue.  The Security Groups are outside the OS, and the specific hostnames being accessed are printed to stdout (or stderr) as APT is running.

Comment: After learning a few things in the last 21 months, it's pretty clear that the only way to really solve this is to go immutable.  That is, all of the updates to packages are done _before_ you spin up the EC2 instance.  When a package update is needed, a new AMI is created with those updates & a new EC2 instance is spun up with it.  The security groups for the EC2 instance never allow access to the package stores.